# ¿Como modificar una escena de Javafx desde el código y el Scene builder a la vez?

Tags: javafx, interfaz-gráfica, model-view-controller, fxml

El problema es que tengo un archivo FXML en el cual necesitaba un GridPane de 30*16 para un buscaminas. Me parecía muy pesado hacerlo a mano así que lo hice en código con un ciclo en la clase main dentro del método initialize. Pero ahora por mas que modifique cosas desde el Scenebuilder no cambia ya que el initialize sigue en lo mismo. ¿Como puedo lograr que los cambios que haga en cada parte (Código y Scenebuilder) no se cancelen entre ellos por asi decirlo?

Comment: Yo usaría el IDE llamado [tag:intellij-idea], te pone dos pestañas una para vista de código y en otra embebe tu scene builder

Answer (score 0):

Podrias poner tu codigo para ver que es lo que quieres modificar. 
Lo que modificas desde codigo no lo vez en el SceneBuilder, pero si puedes dejar una "base" desde el scene builder y completar tu GUI desde codigo.